# Using LAG function with higher offset

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, window-functions

Suppose we have the following input table

```
cat  | value | position
------------------------
1    | A     |   1
1    | B     |   2
1    | C     |   3
1    | D     |   4
2    | C     |   1
2    | B     |   2 
2    | A     |   3
2    | D     |   4
```

As you can see, the values `A,B,C,D` change `position` in each `category`, I want to track this change by adding a column `change` in front of each `value`, the output should look like this:

```
    cat  | value | position | change
    ---------------------------------
    1    | A     |   1      |  NULL
    1    | B     |   2      |  NULL
    1    | C     |   3      |  NULL
    1    | D     |   4      |  NULL
    2    | C     |   1      |   2
    2    | B     |   2      |   0
    2    | A     |   3      |  -2
    2    | D     |   4      |   0
```

For example `C` was in position `3` in category `1` and moved to position `1` in category 2 and therefore has a `change` of `2`. I tried inmplementing this using the `LAG()` function with an offset of 4 but I failed, how can I write this query.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` - with the proper `partition by` clause:

```
select
    t.*,
    lag(position) over(partition by value order by cat) - position change
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `lag()` with the right `partition by`:

```
select t.*,
       (lag(position) over (partition by value order by cat) - position) as change
from t;
```

Here is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . No (but the subtraction was in the wrong direction).  The naming of columns is a bit arcane:  `cat` is a number and `value` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` and then `order by` to maintain original order. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gpHLjqXik1jNexWWn4FwEa/0).

```
select
    *,
    lag(position) over (partition by value order by cat) - position as change
from yourTable
order by
    cat, position
```

output:

```
| cat | value | position | change |
| --- | ----- | -------- | ------ |
| 1   | A     | 1        | null   |
| 1   | B     | 2        | null   |
| 1   | C     | 3        | null   |
| 1   | D     | 4        | null   |
| 2   | C     | 1        | 2      |
| 2   | B     | 2        | 0      |
| 2   | A     | 3        | -2     |
| 2   | D     | 4        | 0      |
```